# folder permissions in liferay

Tags: liferay-ide

Can any one answer how to change folder permissions to a customized role in liferay? i am trying to do it through control panel. My main aim is to give only document uploading permission to a role.

thanks in advance.

Comment: In the Document Library portlet?

Answer (score 1):

Within the Control Panel > Documents and Media, edit the permissions of the folder you wish to restrict.

[image]
[image]

Adjust the permissions accordingly, e.g. your role which can upload documents, could possibly have everything tick. Make sure you limit the other roles, e.g. Site Members, Users and Guests may only have the view permission ticked

[image]

Comment: Is there a programmatic way? Would be great to get some feedback!